# Is REST API created by Sails.js really RESTful and following the convention?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js, watermark

Based on a book I was reading and few articles, the way to specify your REST API is to make use of most HTTP methods, rather than tunnel GET method into creating, how it's shown in demo for Sails.js, you can create model instances simply by making GET request to

```
/modelName/create?property=value
```

Well, that's not RESTful at all. Instead, we should be making PUT request to `/modelName` . Or, am I missing here something?

Comment: You are perfectly right. A get request should be a _safe_ (nullipotent) method, which should return more or less the same data structure no matter how often it is called, but more importantly, should not modify the data structure on its own.

Comment: Github Issues is probably the right place to post this question.

Comment: You can also get live community support for sails.js in our gitter chat room: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a REST API, there are two ways almost all resources are created by a user.

1. A `POST` to the collection that will contain the new resource:

   ```
   [Request]
   POST /gizmos
   {
       "name": "widget"
   }

   [Response]
   201 Created
   Location: /gizmos/71
   ```
2. Or a `PUT` of the new resource directly to its location:

   ```
   [Request]
   PUT /gizmos/71
   {
       "name": "widget"
   }

   [Response]
   204 No Content
   ```

Creating a resource by doing `GET /gizmos/create` is bad.

- `GET` should not change anything on the service. Doing it 0, 1, or 1000 times should all have the same effect: no effect.
- The URL should not have a verb in it. The URL should be a noun. The HTTP method - `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` - is the verb.

Comment: Yea, exactly! Because of safety and idempotence properties. I know that, but still was confused why the API is automatically created like that (having a lot of stars on GitHub) and was wondering if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are. What you've learned from the demo is a shortcut or helpers to acces rest actions from browser url bar which is not restful at all. It's for testing purpose (enabled by default) and shouldn't be used in production.

Use http verbs to make an request to your controllers  e.g. a `DELETE` request to `/user/1` will delete a user with id 1. And that's very restful.